High current passing thru battery
Will running a 20 amp dc to dc charger to charge a 50 amp or 100 amp lifepo4 battery off my 70 amp starter battery, when driving and being powered by the vehicle alternator, cause any damage to the starter battery or alternator, with the constant 20 amp current flow thru the the starter battery?

if you were driving, why would any current from the starter battery? It should all come from the alternator, since it's output voltage is higher than the battery, right?

Can a 70Ah starter battery handle 20 amps being pushed thru it for 1 or 2 hrs., without buckling plates?

yes, 0.5C (35A) should be no problem for charge or discharge or longevity.

Charging under load should not go above float voltage to prevent extended CV stress

I think you mean Ah (Amp-hr) capacity batteries not amp.
Cars depending on size can have alternators that supply 100A more or less, so with the help of your 70Ah starter battery certainly has the capacity to supply 20A when it can start a car in winter with up to 500 Amps at 0'C if new with a 500 CCA (cold cranking Amps)
If the 20A dcdc charger is a proper LiFePo4  charger, there is no problem as defined you have more than adequate capacity.

Can the the 70Ah starter battery handle 20 amps being pushed thru it for an hour or so?

It should but recharge slow after to 90% capacity if this is daily for longer life.
